# SetWindowsHookEx Help on Host Machine

Tags: windows, keyboard, hook

I've written a program which wires up a keyboard hook to listen out for F12 to be pressed, on receipt of F12 being pressed I fire an event to start a separate process in my main program.

This works beautifully on my host computer and and while any other app on the machine has focus, but the keyboard hook stops working when a full screen RDP session is focused or virtual machine running in VMWare is focused.

I use SetWindowsHookEx to set up the keyboard hook as follows:

```
public static int KeyboardHook;

public void AwaitKeyboard(IntPtr handle)
{
    _keyboardHookProcedure = new HookProc(KeyboardHookProc);
    KeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _keyboardHookProcedure, handle, 0);
}
```

Then inside the KeyboardHookProc method I can add code to do something with the main window

```
public static int KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    if (mainWindow != null)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            if (vkCode == mainWindow.KeyboardShortcutCode) // Keyboard shortcut pressed
            {
                mainWindow.KeyboardShortcutPressed();
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

This all works fine for apps on my host machine. But the moment a VM or full screen RDP window is activated, the KeyboardHookProc method is never invoked.

I've read suggestions that I could clear the hook and re-set it whenever the active window changes in Windows. I have tried that and got that working, but re-setting up the hook didn't fix the problem as KeyboardHookProc is still not invoked when in a VM or RDP.

The moment I return to the host machine and press F12 my keyboard hook springs to life and operates as I need it to.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a kernel driver or something before you in the hook chain is eating the key. This is probably by design as far as those other products are concerned.

I see the same issue on my machine, VirtualBox is eating my Foobar2000 hotkeys when it has focus.

`WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is pretty much as low as you can go in usermode. You could try [raw input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) but I doubt that is going to work.

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks for your message, it led to a few ideas. I've tried a variety of things to get this working, I even wrote a service to see what messages the hook might pick up at system level. But I give up, I'll have to just not support this on the host from a virtualised platform.

Comment: I just tried as well, Raw Input and low level hooks such as `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` or `WH_MOUSE_LL` do not work while using a virtual machine. It seems there is no solution for this in usermode.